# How to start and stop children Partical System?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just how the title states, I'm trying to start and stop a "complex" partical system in unity 3D with a timer using Invoke function, basically a fire emission from torches.
The problem is, I can stop the PS (partical System), but I can't restart it.

I've tried accessing `GetComponentsInChildren` and tagging the children of the PS with different tags before creating an array off of them.
As I said before, I can successfuly stop the PS, by tagging the main one and using `GetComponent<PartycalSystem>` for each object in an array before using the `Stop()` function. But for some reason I can't restart it the same way, with the `Start()` function.

```c#
public bool blindmode = false;
public GameObject[] lightfx;
public GameObject[] torches;

void Start()
{
    //getting the reference to the light Objects 
    torches = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("light");
    lightfx = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("fx");        
}

void Update()
{
    if (blindmode==false)
    {
        Invoke("blindmodeon", 20);

    }
    if (blindmode==true)
    {
        Invoke("blindmodeoff", 20);

    }
}

void blindmodeon()
{
    blindmode = true;

    foreach (GameObject torch in torches)
    {
        var fire = torch.GetComponent<Light>();
        fire.enabled = false;
    }

    foreach (GameObject fire in lightfx)
    {
        var flame = fire.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        flame.Stop();
    }
}
```

In this last section of the code, I disable both lights and PS. Since the lights part works perfectly, I'd like you to look at the ParticleSystem only.

```c#
void blindmodeoff()
{
    blindmode = false;
    foreach (GameObject torch in torches)
    {
        var fire = torch.GetComponent<Light>();
        fire.enabled = true;
    }

    foreach (GameObject fire in lightfx)
    {
        var flame = fire.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        flame.Play();
        var child1 = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        child1.Play();
        var child2 = transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        child1.Play();
        var child3 = transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        child1.Play();
        var child4 = transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        child1.Play();
    }
}
```

This was my last try, which also failed to re-enable the PS. As you can guess from it, the PS has its mother PS and 4 children in it.

The torches spawn with the PS active. The first timer invoked stops the PS successfuly. The second timer is supposed to restart it, creating a loop of On and Off with said timers, but it fails to do so. I've tried many things, including with enabling emissions, but nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you attached to the question is a part of the core script (this script is a single for the whole scene or it placed on several GameObjects)? Are there any errors in console?

Comment: The script is attached to an empty object. No errors in the console regarding this script nor gameObjects.

Comment: If this code (script) is attached to an empty object, and that object doesn't contains some child object, there's should be an error log message (because of `transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```c#
void Update()
{
    if (blindmode==false)
    {
        Invoke("blindmodeon", 20);

    }
    if (blindmode==true)
    {
        Invoke("blindmodeoff", 20);

    }
}
```

you are repeatedly adding an invoke ... every frame so later after 20 seconds for the next twenty seconds you probably get the invoked method which contradicts to what you wanted to do.

It seems to me you want to turn of the lights for 20 seconds, and then turn them on for 20 seconds all the time right?

---

I would suggest using a single method like

```c#
private bool blindmode;

private void ToggleLights()
{
    // invert the flag
    blindmode = !blindmode;

    foreach (var torch in torches)
    {
        var fire = torch.GetComponent<Light>();
        // set according to the flag
        fire.enabled = !blindmode;
    }

    foreach (var fire in lightfx)
    {
        // here I would do GetComponentsInChildren
        // passing true so we get also inactive children
        var particleSystems = fire.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>(true);
        foreach(var system in particleSystems)
        {
            // according to the blindmode
            if(blindmode) 
                system.Stop();
            else
                system.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

So you could either do that using [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

```c#
private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("ToggleLights", 0, 20f);
}
```

Or you could also use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```c#
// yes, Start can be a Coroutine
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
        ToggleLights();
        yield return WaitForSeconds(20f);
    }
}
```

or if your want to stick to the `Update` method use a timer like

```c#
private float timer = 20f;

private void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer > 0) return;

    ToggleLights();

    timer = 20f;
}
```

---

In general try to avoid those repeated calls of `GetComponent` and `GetComponentsInChildren`! Rather make the call once e.g. in `Awake` and re-use the references like

```c#
// rather directly store the type you want
public List<Light> torches = new List<Light>();
public List<ParticleSystem> lightfx = new List<ParticleSystem>();

private void Awake()
{
    //getting the reference to the light Objects 
    var torchObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("light");
    var lightfxObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("fx");  

    foreach(var torch in torchObjects)
    {
        torches.Add(torch.GetComponent<Light>());
    }      

    foreach(var fx in lightfxObjects)
    {
        lightfx.AddRange(fx.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>(true));
    }     
}
```

and then later directly use

```c#
foreach (var torch in torches)
{
    torch.enabled = !blindmode;
}

foreach (var fire in lightfx)
{
    if(blindmode) 
        fire.Stop();
    else
        fire.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort!
I can't test this at the moment, but as soon as I test it I will surely reply.

Comment: You are a life saver!
I had no idea the Invokes could overlap themselves, since each of these invokes were sort of nullifying one another.
This worked like a charm:
I used the Togglelights() function with the timer on the Update just like you said. 
Thank you very much. Now the lights and PS are working great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```c#
void blindmodeoff()
{
    blindmode = false;

    foreach (GameObject torch in torches)
    {
        torch.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
    }

    foreach (GameObject fire in lightfx)
    {
        fire.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            fire.GetChild(i).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It's still not working though. I tried like that and with GetComponentInChildren<PartycalSystem>().

Comment: @Weedosaurus, First of all, I updated the code in my answer, because there was a problem (missing semicolon). Anyway, in that case lightfx array should contain all of the parent objects. And those parent objects contains four child objects with a Particle System on each?

Comment: @Weedosaurus note the missing `s` in `GetComponentInChildren<ParticalSystem>()` .. this will only return the first encountered component, not all of them .. besides it is `Particle` not `Partycle`

Comment: I did notice those. These were just typos while writing here on stackoverflow. I apologise. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Nitro557 Yes, that's exactly it. lightfx has 4 parents tagged "fx" with 4 children with particle systems each.